# Finding a more concise way to add values to empty list Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am new to Python and while my task is deemed correct, I know there is a more efficient way to write the code and am looking for advice.

My goal is to count the number of scores (between 1-6) of a dice roll and assign each number to a list. In this case I know the value of the dice roll 'N' - 1 will be the index at which it is added to the list but I am unsure as to how to go about writing it.

```
import random

dice = [0]*6
for roll in range(1001): 
N = random.randint(1,6)
if N == 1:
    dice[0] = dice[0] + 1
if N == 2:
    dice[1] = dice[1] + 1
if N == 3:
    dice[2] = dice[2] + 1
if N == 4:
    dice[3] = dice[3] + 1
if N == 5:
    dice[4] = dice[4] + 1
if N == 6:
    dice[5] = dice[5] + 1
print(f' the number of times the dice rolled 1-6 is as follows {dice}')
```

Comment: Why not code `dice[N-1] = dice[N-1] + 1` ?

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use N-1 for the index of the list.

```
dice[N-1] += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with lists of random values, I recommend numpy:

```
import numpy as np
_, counts = np.unique(np.random.randint(1,7, 1000), return_counts=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```py
dice = [0]*6
for roll in range(1001):
    dice[random.randint(0, 5)] += 1
print(f' the number of times the dice rolled 1-6 is as follows {dice}')
```

The list is being indexed with `N-1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
a = random.sample(range(1, 1001), 6)
print(a)
```

This could brief a lot more what you are looking for
https://pynative.com/python-random-sample/